# How to stop and play multiple sounds in HTML5 without overlapping them?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm using javascript **Audio** class to play different audio files in background in an HTML5 application.
Every audio file is bound to the click event of a button.

Now what I want to achieve is that when a button is clicked, the current audio in progress should stop immediately and the one bound to that specific button should start.

I've tried to use **pause()** and **mute()** methods but in both cases the audios overlap for a very small instance of time (<=1 second).

Is there any solution for this problem?  Below is the code I'm using currently:

```
    if (sound === null) {  
        sound = new Audio("sounds/" + audioId + ".mp3");  
        sound.play();        
    }  
    else {
          sound.pause();  
          sound.src = "sounds/" + audioId + ".mp3";  
          sound.play();  
    }
```

Comment: where is the pause() function being called in your function ?

Comment: Oops! I forgot to add that earlier. It's on line#6 and I tried to call mute() on the same line as well as both on two different lines and then called play() after changing the "src" but the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `played()` this function Sets or returns if the audio/video is paused or not.

**Firstly**, you pause the audio and then check if audio is paused or not using `paused()` after that play sound,instead of play audio just after pause.

Comment: I'm not using any <audio> tag in html. I'm manipulating the Audio() object through javascript so I think your answer will not help :(

Comment: @SibtainNorain: oh.. i didn't get your question earlier sorry for the not reliable answer this answer is only work with `<audio>` tag.

Comment: If problem exist you can comment again.